# Check if service is Enabled, Disabled, Running or Stopped

Tags: systemd, opensuse

Is it possible to check if a service is either enabled, disabled, running or stopped?

I know I can use `service $app status` to see if it's running or dead, but how can I tell if the service has been disabled ?

I am running OpenSUSE.

Comment: Under which service management subsystem?

Comment: This on openSuSE. I've found I can do this using `systemctl is-enabled $app`

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This on openSuSE.

I've found I can do this using `systemctl is-enabled $app`

Comment: Works on Amazon Linux as well!

Comment: Works on RHEL as well

Comment: Also works on Ubuntu!

Comment: Also works on lubuntu 22.04